# É redundante utilizar LIMIT em uma QUERY cujo ID é chave primária?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

Minha dúvida é se utilizando `LIMIT` haverá algum ganho de performance na `QUERY`.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT descricao FROM produto WHERE id = 9999 LIMIT 1
```

**Tem melhor performance que?**

```
SELECT descricao FROM produto WHERE id = 9999
```

Como talvez ficaria genérico não especificar nenhuma ferramenta, gostaria de respostas refente aos mais conhecidos `SQlite`, `SQL Server`, `PostgreSQL`, `MySQL`, `Oracle` .

Não necessariamente precisa ser todos, mas tenho preferencia no `SQlite` já que roda em dispositivos móveis onde a performance/otimização é mais complexa.

Comment: É, pois só pode retornar uma linha dado que é chave primária.

Comment: Entendi a sua duvida, acredito que em qualquer motor a diferença seja minima (se houver diferença) de ganho e cada motor provavelmente funciona de uma maneira. Acredito que não tenha como responder uma coisa especificamente para a sintaxe do SQL, mas somente por motor, por exemplo no mySQL os motores myIsam e innoDB trabalham de maneiras diferentes.

Comment: Vou editar para especificar os mais utilizados.

Comment: Note que MySQL tem tipos de motores diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a consulta usa como critério a chave primária, sim, é redundante.

Se a consulta usa como critério um índice que não é a chave primária e cujo valor não é único, pode ser, mas não sempre. Por exemplo, se o valor está no final do índice (pior caso), ter `LIMIT` ou não é quase a mesma coisa em termos de desempenho.

Agora, se a consulta usa uma coluna não indexada, pode não ser, essencialmente se a consulta não devolver resultados. [Vale a pena ver como funciona o otimizador do SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html). Há referência a `LIMIT` quando se trata de subconsultas. Em todo caso, não havendo resultados, vai haver o `TABLE SCAN` de qualquer forma.

SQL Server e Oracle não possuem `LIMIT`:

- SQL Server usa `TOP`:

  ```
  SELECT TOP 1 descricao FROM produto WHERE id = 9999
  ```
- Oracle usa `ROWNUM`:

  ```
  SELECT descricao FROM produto WHERE id = 9999 AND ROWNUM <= 1;
  ```

Comment: Você adicionou `TOP` no Oracle, isto está certo?

Comment: Não. Vício de copiar-colar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Nunca parei para pensar nisso mas acho que a melhor forma de descobrir se é mais rápido ou não é usando um recurso para medir o tempo ao executar uma query.

Veja um exemplo abaixo, no caso utilizando sql server:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO       
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO
SELECT ProductID, StartDate, EndDate, StandardCost 
FROM Production.ProductCostHistory
WHERE StandardCost < 500.00;
GO
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

Para mais informações consulte:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190287.aspx